# ReSharper-like addon for NetBeans

Tags: php, ide, netbeans, resharper, netbeans6.8

is there any [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)-like addon for NetBeans (preferably 6.8)? I'm using NetBeans for PHP.

I need following features:

- add some kind of code analysis
- add some intelligent refactoring interface
- enhance current code completion system
- add more options to code highlighting

Currently I'm using multiple external tools, which aren't exactly user-friendly and I'd like to, preferably, have it all in one tool. Perhaps some other PHP IDE have something like this.

**EDIT:** Bit more details in my answer to Jani Hartikainen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you like Resharper that you just should try new PHP IDE from same developers! Refactoring, static code analysis, smart completion - [JetBrains WebIDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/webide/features/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it and I must say it seems better than NetBeans, Eclipse or Zend Studio. They could add also built-in debugger tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can run PHP_CodeSniffer with [this netbeans plugin](http://github.com/beberlei/netbeans-php-enhancements/). Perhaps this will add some analysis you're missing - however perhaps you should be more specific about what kind of analysis you want?

I assume you are aware of the refactoring tools builtin to NetBeans? As far as I know, they are some of the most advanced IDE-integrated ones for PHP right now.

You should also describe what kind of enhancements you'd like for the code completion. NetBeans has very good completion builtin, including support for displaying PHPDoc and code templates for quick inserting of, for example, a ready for loop.

I'm afraid no IDE supports changing highlighting very dramatically. Perhaps you should also explain this better? Why would you change it and how?

Comment: I'm already using PHP Code Sniffer as an external application. Didn't know about this addon, so thanks!

Refactoring tools in IDE itself doesn't seem to be very powerful. As far as I've noticed, it allows you just to rename and delete stuff. I also need to check for unused variables, classes or methods.

NetBeans code completion simply refuses to work sometimes and I have to exit and run IDE again. I need something more stable.

I use highlighting similar to Visual Studio (C#) and some things simply cannot be set in NetBeans, which is sometimes annoying.

Comment: Checks for unused variables etc. do exist - but they are experimental right now (I'm using v6.8-dev). You can find that in `Options -> Editor -> Hints`. I cannot help you with stability problems, but which version are you using? Maybe it's the (unstable) development version?

Comment: Yeah, I have those warnings enabled, but they sometimes tell me I don't use some variables which I use. I've already asked a question about it and it's a confirmed bug. I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Build 200912041610) - should be a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alexey Gopachenko; PhpStorm has probably all of those features for Php. He works on the software and I'm a heavy user of the early access program version.